# I upload a mp3 file to wordpress, I want to let users only listen the part of the mp3 online

Tags: wordpress, mp3

I upload mp3 files in wordpress post, how to let users only listen part of the file online ? and don't let users get the file url ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this plugin called 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpaudio-mp3-player/installation/

So you have to use this shortcode

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[wpaudio url='url.to/your.mp3' text='Artist - Song' dl='0']");?>
```

Comment: but user can cache the mp3 file in explorer cookies,any way more ?